# sencha touch - ajax call to server (url , extra parameter formation)

Tags: ajax, proxy, url-routing, sencha-touch

I am using this to get the result from server

```
controller.allVisitStore =  new Ext.data.Store({ 
                model: 'allVisit',
                autoLoad : true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    id: 'allvisit_app_localstore',
                    url: '/RadMobApp/api',
                    extraParams:{   
                        action:'query',
                        queryName:'GET_ALL_VISIT',
                        authToken: localStorage.getItem("auth_token"),
                        patTicketId: localStorage.getItem("patientId"),
                        retFormat:'XML',
                        keyValuePair:'yes'
                    },
                    // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
                    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
                        // records will have an "T4" tag
                        record: 'data'
                    })
                }
            });
```

but i am not getting any thing.But i formed this url in browser and checked this i got the correct result. now here i want to check is there any problem in the url formation.How to check the url formation with extra parameter which is pass through ajax. I have checked in Inspect element-> network -> api there is no any api request found there.Is anything wrong in my code. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or Chrome's developer tools to see what's going on when that store attempts to load itself. My hunch is that your url is incorrect and should be `url: '/api'` because RadMobApp is probably your app root.